Is there a way to whitelist a set of SD-cards for a single raspi?
I teach courses with Raspberry Pis and I would like to prevent people to bring their own (malicious) SD-cards with them and replace my cards by theirs. I thought about whitelisting (like with a set of whitelisted devices connecting to a network) - is it possible/viable? Or what other options do I have?

enclose the RPi in a secure container

Like a physical case?

yes, a physical case,  with anti-tampering seals
